# Is there any open source program that integrates logs in log4j format in a distributed system to a Cassandra DB?

Tags: log4j, cassandra, integrate

I have a distributed system that all of them use lig4j for log system events.I have a Cassandra cluster that I want to put all of my logs in log4j format in that.
Is there any open source program that integrates logs in log4j format to my Cassandra cluster?

Answer (score 4):

A good choice would be Apache Flume. https://cwiki.apache.org/FLUME/

Flume is distributed log collection engine. It has built in support for log4j: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/flume/UserGuide/#_logging_via_log4j_directly

There is also a plugin for using cassandra as the log storage mechanism instead of hdfs: https://github.com/thobbs/flume-cassandra-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I started an open source project with a custom log4j appender sending the message to a apache cassandra cluster. Project site is: https://github.com/rviper/cassandra-log4j