# How to configure logging in Hadoop / HDP components?

Tags: java, hadoop, log4j, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I have an HDP 2.4 cluster with the following services/components:

1. HBase
2. Kafka
3. MapReduce2
4. Storm
5. Oozie
6. Support services like Zookeeper, Ambari, Yarn, HDFS, etc.

I've been searching for this for several days now and would appreciate some help. I have the following two questions:

1. How do I configure logging at both the application level (we're using log4j) and daemon level for all the services mentioned below?
2. What is the best practice to view all the application level logs for these services in one consolidated place? Does Ambari have something to offer or do we need third party packages (and which ones are good)?

Thanks so much for any assistance you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing an application that leverages one or more HDP services, I would recommend updating the log4j.properties file for each of those services to match the logging level that you desire. The best way to do this is to use the Ambari Admin UI. To edit the log4j.properties of a service, follow the steps below:

> 1. Click any one of the services on the left-hand side of the Dashboard.
> 2. Once the Service Summary page has loaded, click the 'Configs' tab at the top of the screen.
> 3. Click the 'Advanced' tab underneath the Version History Timeline, find the 'Advanced' set of properties and then search for the log4j.properties entry. Failing that, you can search for 'log4j' in the search bar at the top-right of the screen and Ambari will highlight the relevant settings.

See [here](http://eagle.apache.org/images/docs/hdfs-log4j-conf.png) for an image detailing an example of the log4j.properties file for the HDFS service.

Bear in mind that the log files for each of those services would only capture the interaction between your application and that service **only**. If you are working in Java I would personally recommend adding a log4j instance into your application; if you don't know how to do this, my recommendation is to follow [this tutorial](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/log4j-tutorial-adding-log4j-logging-to-your-project/) (found on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495443/how-to-implement-use-log4j)) to get you set up correctly. Depending on how your application calls the APIs of each service you can interrogate the output of the command and log this into your own log file.

---

In terms of viewing log files in one centralised location, you have two options:

1. Upgrade to HDP 2.5 to utilise Ambari Log Search.
2. Stay on HDP 2.4 and create a solution from scratch using Flume.

I'll outline the two options below.

### 1. Upgrade to HDP 2.5 to utilise Ambari Log Search.

I would hazard that the "easier" method (by that I mean requiring the least effort on your part) would be to upgrade your cluster to HDP 2.5. The updated Hortonworks Data Platform brings a big overhaul to Ambari with its latest version, Ambari 2.4. This version includes Ambari Infra which allows you to view all log files, filter by log levels and perform graphing and complex functions thanks to [Ambari Log Search](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.0.1/bk_ambari-user-guide/content/log_search_ui.html).

If it isn't feasible for you to upgrade the entire cluster, another option is to obtain the Ambari 2.4 repository from Hortonworks' website and install it manually. A Hortonworks representative advised me that Ambari 2.4 can run on HDP 2.4 without issue so this may be a feasible alternative... Though I would recommend you check with Hortonworks yourself before attempting this!

The only downside with Ambari Log Search is that you wouldn't be able to include your applications logs in the search - Ambari Log Search is for Hadoop services only.

### 2. Stay on HDP 2.4 and create a solution from scratch using Flume.

If you don't want to upgrade to Ambari 2.4, then other options look to be a little scarce. I don't know of any open source solutions personally and some cursory Googling returns few results. [Apache Chukwa](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Chukwa) and [Cloudera's Scribe](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/10/installing-scribe-for-log-collection/) both are supposed to address distributed log collection in Hadoop but are both 9 years old. There's also [an older Hortonworks process for log collection that leverages Flume](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hadoop_tutorial_visualizing_server_logs/) for the same process which might be worth a look at. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248082/is-there-any-open-source-program-that-integrates-logs-in-log4j-format-in-a-distr) also recommends Flume for other situations. It might be worth putting some thought into collecting logs from each servers `/var/log/` directory using Flume.

The upside of this solution is that your applications log files could be included in the Flume workflow as a Source and included with the other HDP service logs (depending on where you decide to put them).

Comment: Thanks @Fredulom, I understand that we can configure the logging for the daemons using log4j.properties of the respective service but **how do I set the logging config for my application**? For instance, say I have a main class that uses HBase & Mapreduce and my logger name is com.example. Do I set log4j.logger.com.example  in hbase-log4j or hdfs-log4j or yarn-log4j? Which nodes do I include in the config group?

Comment: Also, you recommended Ambari Infra (I'm assuming Ambari Log Search in particular) to view log files. Are there any **other open source solutions to view & search log files that you recommend**?

Comment: I would imagine that whatever service you are leveraging as part of your application would require amending. With the example you specified in your comment, you'd probably want to set both the log4j.properties for hbase and hdfs. That said, the loggers would only log how your application was interfacing with that specific service and nothing else - if you wanted holistic logging for the entire application, you'd need to configure your own log4j instance for that application and that most likely wouldn't be included in the Ambari Log Search functionality in Ambari Infra.

Comment: To answer your second comment, yes Ambari Infra w. Ambari Log Search was what I was talking about. In terms of open source solutions to this, it seems they are few and far between. I don't know of any off the top of my head and cursory Googling into the answer returns few results. [Apache Chukwa](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Chukwa) and  [Cloudera's Scribe](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/10/installing-scribe-for-log-collection/) both are supposed to address distributed log collection in Hadoop but are both 9 years old... [see next comment]

Comment: ...There's also an [older Hortonworks process for log collection that leverages Flume for the same process](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hadoop_tutorial_visualizing_server_logs/) which might be worth a look at if you can't get HDP 2.5 and/or Ambari 2.4 right now. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248082/is-there-any-open-source-program-that-integrates-logs-in-log4j-format-in-a-distr) SO thread also recommends Flume for other situations so it might be worth using Flume (if you have it) to collect logs from your server :)

Comment: Thanks @Fredulom. Can you please elaborate on how to configure our own log4j instance? I would appreciate if you could update your answer

Comment: @Paras I have updated the question - can you let me know if this is sufficient?

Comment: Thanks @Fredulom, really appreciate your help! Your answer is exhaustive and definitely meets our needs. I'll wait for another two days before accepting the correct answer & awarding the bounty, just in case we get another competitive answer.

Comment: Of course, no problem :) let me know if you wanted anything else answering!

Comment: Thanks @Fredulom for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use HDP you should check this article (shows how to configure log4j):

[How to control size of log files for various HDP components?](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/8882/how-to-control-size-of-log-files-for-various-hdp-c.html)

This one is really useful too (shows how to zip HDFS logs using log4j):

[How to rotate as well as zip the NameNode logs using log4j extras feature?](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/50058/using-log4j-extras-how-to-rotate-as-well-as-zip-th.html)